# Detect click inside applet

Tags: javascript, html, css, applet

I have a applet and i want to catch when users do click inside, like a "onclick", this is my code (i´m working in FIREFOX):

```
 <div class="col-sm-6" id="weight-display">
    <div class="row the-box btn-info shadow" style="z-index:1;" >
        <applet width="440" height="115" id="myApplet" MAYSCRIPT
                archive="/applet/CWDisplayApplet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                code="com.dibal.cw.applet.CWDisplayApplet.class" >
            <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" />
        </applet>
        </div>
```

I put onclick inside divs but it don´t works. 
I make a transparent div over applet but i´m working in FIREFOX, and it doesn't work, this is the transparent div:

```
<div class="pulsarapplet" style="background: white; position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 518px; width: 450px;height:115px;z-index:500001 " onclick="alert('BARRUAN')">
</div>
```

when I quit the color and convert this div in transparent... doesn't work.

I need help. Remember **I using FIREFOX**.

Comment: You need to find an alternative to using a Java applet at all. [Firefox will be dropping support for Java applets very soon](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/), and it is already not supported in Chrome, Safari, or Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I know, but is necessary, is a client program and i cant change it. They will use the firefox same versión in that case, to use firefox with applets, thanks ;-)

Comment: Add a `MouseListener`. And be sure to warn the client they'll need to use an obsolescent FF in order to support applets. It's really not worth it. *"but is necessary"* It is necessary that I get a flying pony that excretes ice cream. Not going to make it happen.

Comment: the customer claims to be warned and be aware. It is your application, I can not do anything. :-(, thanks !